# Are substituted sugar/carbohydrate derivatives such as sucralose still sugars/carbohydrates?

Tags: carbohydrates

Sucralose is made from sucralose, with chlorination of 3 of the hydroxyl groups. If broken up into the 2 saccharide-type units, you'll get 1,6-dichloro-1,6-dideoxyfructose and  4-chloro-4-deoxy-D- galactose. Firstly, are those 2 compounds considered to be monosaccharides/sugars? And if so, is sucralose considered a disaccharide/sugar?

They wouldn't conform to the regular general formula for monosaccharides, (CH2O)x, but IUPAC Gold Book (https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/M04021)  says "for Monosaccharides - A term which includes aldoses, ketoses and a wide variety of derivatives. Derivation includes oxidation, deoxygenation, introduction of other substituents, alkylation and acylation of hydroxy groups, and chain branching." At what point would a derivative not be considered a monosaccharide anymore?

[image: Sucralose and sucrose]

Comment: I think as long as the ring structure is intact with the ether bond one may still call it a carbohydrate derivative. For instance cylcodextrins are heavily derivatized for chromatographic purposes such as permethylated cyclodextrin. It is a derivative but *most* of its hydroxyls have been replaced by methyl groups.